# java.lang.NullPointerException in LinkedList<Integer>[] add() method

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, adjacency-list

I'm having problem when i'm adding node in Array of LinkedList.

```
int vertices = 100;
LinkedList<Integer>[] AdjList = new LinkedList[vertices+1];


for (i = 1; i <= vertices; ++i) {         
    for (j = 1; j <= 6 && j + i <= vertices; ++j) {

        AdjList[i].add(j);    //Error occurs here.
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the list before inserting into it. In your first for loop add this line, before the second for loop

```
AdjList[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```